# What is the font color of a checkbox' text when it is not enabled

Tags: c#

I have a label and a checkbox in C#. I just want to let the labels' font color be the same as checkbox's text when it is not enabled, say a kind of gray. Is there any way to do that?

I am trying to change the font color of the label when the box is no enabled. But I cannot find the correct color.

Comment: What type of project? WPF, UWP, ASP, Silverlight, etc? Knowing which can allow someone to look at the default style templates and find the specific color in the docs.

Comment: Could you not just also disable the label? @Mikev's answer touches on that a little.

Answer (score 1):

The `SystemColors` class contains static properties with the standard colors used by most applications,  unless they are using some skinning or any custom colors.

Give it a try with

```
label1.ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
```

The description of the property says:

> Returns: A System.Drawing.Color that is the color of dimmed text.

Answer (score 0):

The exact color of a disabled label font is: `SystemColors.ControlDark`.

So you just have to do something like this:

```
label1.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlDark;
```

Here are two labels, one is enabled = false the other is with `label1.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlDark;`

You can see they are exactly the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPF you can get the color of the checkbox text and set it for the label by using

```
Brush color = _checkBoxName.Foreground;
_labelName.Foreground = color;
```

Comment: I don't think this works when the checkbox is disabled. IIRC, it will report the color as black (for whatever reason) and then your label won't change. But I may also be thinking of Winforms specifically, so take that with a grain of salt.